# How to extract lines when two columns strings are not equal

Tags: text-processing, csv-simple

I have a CSV file that looks like this format:

```
text1,text2,string1,string2
text3,text3,string3,string2
text4,text5,string1,string2
text6,text6,string6,string7
```

I want to extract rows when column1 and column2 are not equal. The expected result in the above example would be:

```
text1,text2,string1,string2
text4,text5,string1,string2
```

When column1 and column2 are not equal. I am familiar with commands that allow me extract specific column like the following to extract the first column:

```
cat input.csv | cut -d ',' -f1 > output.csv
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that this is a *simple CSV* file, without any fancy embedding of commas or newlines *within* the fields of the actual data, you may use `awk` to do this:

```
awk -F ',' '$1 != $2' <input.csv
```

This is a shorthand way of writing

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "," } $1 != $2 { print }' <input.csv
```

and it sets the input field separator to a comma and prints each line if the first and second fields (`$1` and `$2`) are not identical.

An equivalent Perl variant:

```
perl -F ',' -na -e 'print if $F[0] ne $F[1]' <input.csv
```

Comment: Good description.  Even shorter if strip unnecessary quotes/spaces/direction : `awk -F, '$1!=$2' input.csv`

Answer (score 1):

GNU **`sed`** solution:

```
sed -E '/^([^,]+,)\1/d' input.csv
```

The output:

```
text1,text2,string1,string2
text4,text5,string1,string2
```

Comment: Can you please provide explanation. Does this command compares the two columns and print the different column1 and column2? Because I do not care about column3 or column4 at all. The may be different or similar. I do not consider them.

Comment: @user9371654 The command uses a regular expression that will only match those lines that have equal values in the first and second column (literally: "any string not containing a comma, followed by a comma and the same string and comma again").  The  lines that matches are removed from the input, and only the lines that you'd like to see are let through.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F "," '{if ($1 != $2)print $0}' filename
text1,text2,string1,string2
text4,text5,string1,string2
```